# Python: Catching a logging.exception() call

Tags: python

I am trying to catch an exception that is not raised, just logged. Is there any way to do this?

```
def exampleFunction():
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
    except Exception:
        logging.exception('divide by 0 error here.')

try:
    exampleFunction()
except <condition based on if logging.exception was called>
    print('there was a divide by 0 error when I called exampleFunction()')
```

Comment: I sure hope there isn't. If you're interested in knowing whether an exception occurred, why does `exampleFunction` silently swallow that exception?

Comment: There's probably an awful way to do this with `mock`. Let me thing...

Comment: Basically, the `exampleFunction` just swallows the exception so it doesn't break any code that calls it by throwing a random exception (thinks the issue is minor/skippable). But in my specific case, I need to treat it as an exception

Comment: Can or can't you modify `exampleFunction`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have seen this in third party libs  who assume that this is an internal error which nobody every wants to catch - unfortunately, they guessed wrong and I needed to catch that exception.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that exampleFunction is in some horrible third party code that you do not own, otherwise there are lots of better alternatives.

What you can do:

```
import logging # make sure this is the FIRST import of logging
import horrible_third_party_lib

def catch_log(msg):
   # do something when this is called
old_logging = logging.exception
try:
    logging.exception=catch_log
    horrible_third_party_lib.exampleFunction()
finally:
    logging.exception=old_logging
```

You can then do everything you want in the function. It's horrible and sensitive to import order, but I have used this and it works (scikit learn does something similarly repugnant..)

Comment: Is there a way to use the function `catch_log` to actually throw an Exception? Basically, I want to be able to do something where I can raise an Exception in `def catch_log` and do an `except Exception` clause in-between the try: and finally:

Comment: Yes of course, just raise the exception you want to throw

Comment: When I tried raising an Exception in catch_log, it didn't actually end up being caught..

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I am trying to catch an exception
>   The Questions Title should be rewriten to "**I am trying to reraise an exception**"

Read [Python Documentation#raise](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise)
Seems somewhat double work, but you can do it like that:

```
def exampleFunction():
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
    except Exception as e:
        print("logging.exception({})".format(e))
        raise

try:
    exampleFunction()
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print('there was a divide by 0 error when I called exampleFunction()')
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> logging.exception(division by zero)
> there was a divide by 0 error when I called exampleFunction()
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3***

Comment: Using `raise` at the end would be enough to reraise the last exception.

Comment: @metmirr: Please explaine, which **end**?

Comment: I mean this: `except Exception as e: print('...'); raise`